# Response message: Request Entity Too Large in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

**While uploading the audio file from jmeter is returning Response message: Request Entity Too Large in jmeter.**

I am new to jmeter. I am trying to upload a audio file to the api-server with the jmeter then i am getting 413 error.

```
<html><head>
<title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request Entity Too Large</h1>
The requested resource<br />uploadAudio<br />
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in
the request exceeds the capacity limit.
</body></html>
```

But when i am using postman to upload audio file i am getting success in response.

***Please help! Thanks in advance.***

Comment: You obviosly exceeds the limits of a small webhotel ...Upgrade.

Comment: @davidkonrad did you see the line about the same call working through Postman?

Comment: yes.. its working through postman

Comment: Hey guys, i have solved this issue. The issue was in implementation type of http Request in jmeter. I set implemenation type to java and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can write an answer to your own question